# How to add carriage return in SAS code?

Tags: sas

I want to add a carriage return\linebreak\linefeed to the SAS code, so that there are returns in the output xml.

```
data test_JK_merge;
    length body $ 1500;
    set test_JK;
    body=strip(termEntry_st)||"&#13;"||strip(TS_Status)||strip(langset_en_st)||strip(nttG)||strip(langset_en_ed)||strip(termEntry_ed);
    /*merged=strip(termEntry_st)||"'0A'X"||strip(TS_Status)||"<br />"||strip(langset_en_st)||"<br />"||strip(nttG)||"<br />"||strip(langset_en_ed)||"<br />"||strip(termEntry_ed);*/
    keep body;
run;

libname outxml xml "U:\Projects\...\test2.mtf.xml";

data outxml.text;
    set test_JK_merge;
run;
```

I have tried different ways, such as &#13;, 'OA'X, &#10;,<br />etc
But none of them worked. Does anybody can help out?

**Actual result:**

```
<TEXT>
  <body><termEntry id=1>&#13;<note type="TS_Status">ELC TERM present in OCS_Help_xml OCS_properties</note><langSet lang="eng-us">ntig><termGrp><term>ARM</term></termGrp></ntig></langSet></termEntry></body> 
 </TEXT>
```

**Expected result:**

```
    <TEXT>
      <body><termEntry id=1>
<note type="TS_Status">ELC TERM present in OCS_Help_xml OCS_properties</note><langSet lang="eng-us">ntig><termGrp><term>ARM</term></termGrp></ntig></langSet></termEntry></body> 
     </TEXT>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm actually slightly surprised that you get

```
<body><termEntry ...
```

by using LIBNAME XML. I might be inclined to generate the XML manually from a DATA step.

LIBNAME XML with style=generic (the default) will produce output of the form

```
<dsname>
   <columnname>column value</columnname>
</dsname>
<dsname>
   <columnname>column value</columnname>
</dsname>
..etc...
```

i.e one tag `<dsname>` for each record in your input file with a tag under it for each variable in the data set. In order that SAS can then read the result back in it will escape any value, so that if the variable in the data set is a string and contains any of the characters `<`, `&` etc it won't "confuse" the XML. So in your case, where the variable in the data set has a value something like

```
<termEntry id=1>...</termEntry>
```

then I'd expect the output from libname XML to be something like

```
<TEXT>
    <body> &lt;termEntry id=1&gt;&lt;/termEntry&gt; </body>
</TEXT
```

The options seem to be either to understand how to use XMLMap with LIBNAME XML in order to generate the XML you want (may not be possible depending on what version of SAS you have), or to generate the XML manually using a DATA step:

```
data test_JK;
    termEntry_st = "<termEntry id=1>";
    termEntry_ed = "</termEntry>";
    TS_Status = "<note type='TS_Status'>ELC TERM present in OCS_Help_xml OCS_properties</note>";
    langset_en_st = "<langSet lang='eng-us'>";
    langset_en_ed = "</langSet>";
    nttG = "<ntig><termGrp><term>ARM</term></termGrp></ntig>";

data _null_;
    set test_JK end=e;
    file "tmp.xml";

    if _n_ eq 1 then do;
       put "<something>";
    end;

    put "  <text>";
    put "    <body>" +(-1) termEntry_st;
    put TS_Status +(-1) langset_en_st +(-1) nttG +(-1) langset_en_ed +(-1) termEntry_ed  + (-1) "</body>";
    put "  </text>";

    if e then do;
       put "</something>";
    end;
 run;
```

Comment: Hi Tom, now I understand what you mean. I'm trying with **put** statement, but met a problem as follows:

Comment: @Tom:When the length of characters in one variable reaches **256**, a hard-return is added automatically, which destroy xml structure and well-formness, hence an error when loading the xml in IE. Do you know how to prevent this problem?

Comment: @Tom: An example is shown below '<termEntry id="1">........</note>**<note 
type**="TS_User2">52'
If you copy the code into Word, you will see a hard-return between **note** and **type**

Comment: @Tom: Just found out that all comments here are normalized, meaning you can see the return. But you can try at your side.

Comment: Probably the 256 is caused by the record length on the file. The default for text files is 256. You could try adding lrecl=32767 (say) as an option on the file statement.

Comment: @Tom:You are right. I happened to find out the problem yesterday:)
I set it with the length of longest record using a macro variable. Anyway, it works. Thanks a lot for your help.
Cheers